# How to make activity indicator needs to be placed centre in all devices using constraints programmatically in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Here I am having customized activity indicator to place centre in all devices but I am unable to place it centre can anyone help me how to implement this ?

here is the code for activity indicator

```
 func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
        container.frame = uiView.frame
        container.center = uiView.center
        container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

        loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
        loadingView.center = uiView.center
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
        loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        customActivityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        customActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
        customActivityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)

        loadingView.addSubview(customActivityIndicator)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        container.addSubview(loadingView)
        contentView.addSubview(container)
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: container,
            attribute: .centerX,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: view,
            attribute: .centerX,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0
            ).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: container,
            attribute: .centerY,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: view,
            attribute: .centerY,
            multiplier: 1.0, 
            constant: 0.0
            ).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 50).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 350).isActive = true
        customActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
    func hideActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
        customActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        container.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Here is the code for using the above function

```
func buyNowActionForNewCollection(button: UIButton){
        if loginCheck == 1 {
            showActivityIndicator(uiView: contentView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .centerX and .centerY constraints should work, so maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Make sure you include `customActivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, otherwise iOS will make automatic constraints based on the frame you gave it - the container view's center at the moment of creating the activity indicator. You can see if that's the problem by the console messages you get; it would show you a conflicting constraints error.

Another potential problem is that, for some reason, this won't work in a UITableViewController or UICollectionViewController; in that case, you would have to replace it with a generic UIViewController subclass and create the table view / collection view yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am using [DGActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGActivityIndicatorView) a third party GITHUB lib.

Just copy the whole class and try it like below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import DGActivityIndicatorView

class ViewUtils {

    static let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)

    static func addActivityView(view : UIView) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        window.viewWithTag(111)?.removeFromSuperview()
        let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
        loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.size.width , height: window.frame.size.height + 80 )
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.99, green: 0.99, blue: 0.99, alpha: 0.5)
        loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        loadingView.tag = 111

        let activityIndicator = DGActivityIndicatorView(type: .ballBeat, tintColor: UIColor.darkGray, size: 50.0)
        activityIndicator?.frame = CGRect(x: loadingView.frame.size.width/2 , y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2, width: 40, height: 20)
        activityIndicator?.center = view.center
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        activityIndicator?.startAnimating()
        loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator!)
        window.addSubview(loadingView)
    }

    static func removeActivityView(view : UIView) {
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        window.viewWithTag(111)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This is how u need to call it in your respective class.

```
ViewUtils.addActivityView(view: self.view)
ViewUtils.removeActivityView(view: self.view)
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: should I need to give constraints for it to display it in center in all devices ?

Comment: not required it will take the center on every device , try the above code and let me know.

Comment: I need to include third party files in my app ?

Comment: if u want to u can, that is nice lib and verity of customization, just add the pod and import the class that's it. otherwise u can use default indicator instead of that.

Comment: without pod I am trying to implement is it able to install manually

Comment: yes , u can use default one instead of DGActivityIndicatorView.